# Finding lifted paths, homotopy lifting

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am given a covering map $p: \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$ defined by $p(r, \theta)=(r \cos 2 \theta,r \sin 2 \theta)$

Let $\alpha: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$ defined by $\alpha(t)=(2-t,0)$.

I want to find the lift of $\alpha$, namely $\tilde{\alpha}(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha=p \circ \tilde{\alpha}$

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
 I need $\tilde{\alpha}$ to be such that $r \sin \theta =0$ and $r \cos \theta =2-t$

I am really not sure how to solve this. It is probably just algebra but I would really appreciate some hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To find the lift, define $\tilde\alpha(t) = (r=f(t) , \theta=g(t))$

$$\alpha = ( 2-t,0) = p \circ \tilde \alpha = ( f(t) \cos( 2 g(t) ) , f(t) \sin( 2 g(t)) $$

From here it's easy to see if we take

$$f(t) = \frac{2-t}{ \cos ( 2 g(t) ) } = \pm( 2-t) \quad \& \quad g(t) = \frac{1}{2} (n \pi)\quad  \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

This will lift will project down to the curve you want, the problem is your projection map doesn't give you much freedom.

Comment: I am not sure what to do with this. $f(t)= \pm (2-t)$ does not really help find $\tilde{\alpha}$.

Comment: I'm assuming $\alpha = (r, \theta) = ( 2-t,0)$, and if that is the case we see that $\tilde \alpha = (r,\theta) = ( \pm ( 2-t) , n \pi /2 )$